# Including a defined resource in a class

Tags: puppet

I've read [the documentation](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/puppet_language.html) over but I cannot figure out how to include a defined resource. I've tired:

```
include User::Admin['beamin']
```

I get:

```
err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: undefined method `downcase' for User::Admin[beamin]{:name=>"beamin"}:Puppet::Resource at /etc/puppet/modules/team/manifests/uni.pp:3 on node u1x2.example.com
```

How am I suppose to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An answer from a [Puppet Users Google group](http://groups.google.com/group/puppet-users) member:

> Defined resources aren't included. They are declared, just like other
>   resources. You might do this:
>
> notify { "woo!": }
>
> And if you define a resource called "foo", then you can also do this:
>
> foo { "woo!": }
>
> Reading through the serverless puppet guide (also at
>   docs.puppetlabs.com) might be a better introduction than the language
>   guide.